# Snap error: main.go:220: WARNING: cannot create syslog logger

Tags: apt, snap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu installed on Windows 10 in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and I am getting this problem whenever I run `snap install <package>` or `snap list`.

Has anyone had a similar error?

Steps to reproduce:
1. Install Ubuntu on Windows 10 WSL
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install snapd`
4. `snap list (or) snap install ffsend`

NB: I have also tried `sudo snap list` and it returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snap requires the "System and Service Manager" systemd](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/windows-subsystem-for-linux/216/9) which is a missing piece in WSL. Right now snap is not supported in WSL.

When running the command `snap install htop` I receive the following info:

> Interacting with snapd is not yet supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux.
>   This command has been left available for documentation purposes only.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with WSL on Windows 10 version 1809 build 17763.379.